# Execute an array of functions

Tags: jquery, arrays, function

I'm using a mixture of d3.js and jQuery to create a visualisation. I have 3 functions that I'm trying to put into an array and then execute one after the other but I don't think I'm doing it correctly as when I click "play" nothing happens. Here's my code:

```
var functionsArray = [oct12,oct13,oct14];

$('#play').click(function(){ 
for (var i = 0; i < functionsArray.length; i++){
    functionsArray[i];  
}
```

I'll put up a jsfiddle shortly...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call the function too.

```
functionsArray[i]();
```

Answer (score 2):

use `$.each`

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/4D9vj/)**

```
var functionsArray = [oct12,oct13,oct14];

$(functionsArray).each(function(key, val){
 val();
});

function oct12(){
 alert('oct12');
}

function oct13(){
 alert('oct13');
}

function oct14(){
  alert('oct14');
}
```

​